# Extending Clearance gem controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, clearance, class-extensions, thoughtbot

I am trying to extend clearances controllers to pass through some other form elements

I have currently done the following but it doesn't appear to be working and is returning `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController
  private

  def user_from_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :mobile, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you share your controller code that handles `create` and `update` actions?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/blob/master/app/controllers/clearance/users_controller.rb

Comment: seems to have worked updating to user_params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The create action calls `user_from_params`, which explicitly calls the Clearance `user_params` to validate strong parameters.  The `user_from_params` that defined in the derived class is not getting called, hence the exception.

You can name the strong parameters method in your derived class `user_params`.  The derived method will then simply override the method of the same name in the base class, regardless of the fact that the base method is private.